# What is the opposite to symbolic computation?

Tags: symbolic-math

I was wondering what the opposite concept(s) to symbolic computation is(are)? In other words, what does symbolic computation belong to, and what other subcategories does it have besides symbolic computation in the same classification?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is *numeric computation.*